# New to MongoDB Can not run command mongo

Tags: windows, mongodb

I was trying to run MongoDB:

```
   E:\mongo\bin>mongod
    mongod --help for help and startup options
    Sun Nov 06 18:48:37
    Sun Nov 06 18:48:37 warning: 32-bit servers don't have journaling enabled by default. Please use --journal if you want durability.
    Sun Nov 06 18:48:37
    Sun Nov 06 18:48:37 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=7108 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 32-bit host=pykhmer-PC
    Sun Nov 06 18:48:37 [initandlisten]
    Sun Nov 06 18:48:37 [initandlisten] ** NOTE: when using MongoDB 32 bit, you are limited to about 2 gigabytes of data
    Sun Nov 06 18:48:37 [initandlisten] **       see http://blog.mongodb.org/post/137788967/32-bit-limitations
    Sun Nov 06 18:48:37 [initandlisten] **       with --journal, the limit is lower
    Sun Nov 06 18:48:37 [initandlisten]
    Sun Nov 06 18:48:37 [initandlisten] db version v2.0.1, pdfile version 4.5
    Sun Nov 06 18:48:37 [initandlisten] git version: 3a5cf0e2134a830d38d2d1aae7e88cac31bdd684
    Sun Nov 06 18:48:37 [initandlisten] build info: windows (5, 1, 2600, 2, 'Service Pack 3') BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_42
    Sun Nov 06 18:48:37 [initandlisten] options: {}
    Sun Nov 06 18:48:37 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10296 dbpath (/data/db) does not exist, terminating
    Sun Nov 06 18:48:37 dbexit:
    Sun Nov 06 18:48:37 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
    Sun Nov 06 18:48:37 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
    Sun Nov 06 18:48:37 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
    Sun Nov 06 18:48:37 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
    Sun Nov 06 18:48:37 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
    Sun Nov 06 18:48:37 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
    Sun Nov 06 18:48:37 dbexit: really exiting now

E:\mongo\bin>mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.1
connecting to: test
Sun Nov 06 18:48:42 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1 shell/mongo.js:84
exception: connect failed

E:\mongo>ls
GNU-AGPL-3.0  README  THIRD-PARTY-NOTICES  bin  data
```

I was looking at http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Quickstart+Windows
and following the instructions.
Could anyone tell me what is the problem with running MongoDB (I am using Windows 7)?

Comment: Downvoted, as reading the logs can not be asked too much, even from somebody who is new. The line just before the shutdown starts clearly states what is happening.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I think your log output states it clearly;

```
exception in initAndListen: 10296 dbpath (/data/db) does not exist, terminating
```

You may simply create this directory or better to [define it](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#dbpath) as a configuration value within your configuration file then use it as `mongod -f C:\path\to\your\mongodb.conf`.

Comment: no worries. just get rid of that windowz thing, which will make you more familiar to software development..

Comment: By default, MongoDB looks in the:  c:\data\db  folder, so you could also just create that directory structure, and the MongoDB database process won't yell at you.

Comment: I placed data\db in many places as well as using the --dbpath option to no avail. Only thing that worked was creating the c:\data\db folder as Miguel Sevilla suggested.

Answer (score 166):

After installing the MongoDB you should manually create a data folder.

```
By default MongoDB will store data in /data/db, 
but it won't automatically create that directory. To create it, do:

$ sudo mkdir -p /data/db/
$ sudo chown `id -u` /data/db

You can also tell MongoDB to use a different data directory,
with the --dbpath option.
```

[For more detailed information go to MongoDB wiki page.](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Quickstart+OS+X#QuickstartOSX-Createadatadirectory)

Comment: This should be the answer - it worked and was more helpful then "Read the documentation".

Comment: Also of note, I just found this out today, if you start mongo with `service mongodb start` it automatically reads the `/etc/mongod.conf` file and you don't need to specify your --dbpath or --config variables each time you start! This definitely works for the 10gen install but I'm not sure about others as I haven't tried them.

Answer (score 28):

Specify the database path explicitly like so, and see if that resolves the issue.

```
mongod --dbpath data/db
```

Comment: If the directory does not exist it will fail under mongo version 4.2

Answer (score 21):

```
mongod --dbpath "c://data/db"
```

run the above code, this will start the server.

Answer (score 6):

For **Windows 7**

You may specify an alternate path for `\data\db` with the **dbpath setting for mongod.exe**,

as in the following example:

```
c:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --dbpath c:\mongodb\data\db
```

or

you can **set dbpath through Configuration File**.

Answer (score 4):

Check that path to database data files exists ;) :

> Sun Nov 06 18:48:37 [initandlisten] **exception** in initAndListen: 10296
>   **dbpath (/data/db) does not exist**, terminating

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me (if it applies that you also see the lock file):

```
first>youridhere@ubuntu:/var/lib/mongodb$ sudo service mongodb start 
then >youridhere@ubuntu:/var/lib/mongodb$ sudo rm mongod.lock*
```

Answer (score 2):

After several attempts this works for me on **Windows 7** env.:

Initially directory to which you have copied all MongDB sources has such view:

```
bsondump.exe
mongo.exe
mongod.exe
mongod.pdb
mongodump.exe
mongoexport.exe
mongofiles.exe
mongoimport.exe
mongooplog.exe
mongoperf.exe
mongorestore.exe
mongos.exe
mongos.pdb
mongostat.exe
mongotop.exe
```

All you need is to add **data** directory and **db** directory nested( data/db )
Final view should look like this:

```
data
bsondump.exe
mongo.exe
mongod.exe
mongod.pdb
mongodump.exe
mongoexport.exe
mongofiles.exe
mongoimport.exe
mongooplog.exe
mongoperf.exe
mongorestore.exe
mongos.exe
mongos.pdb
mongostat.exe
mongotop.exe
```

Than simply type in directory where MongoDB sources and data/db dirs exist this command:

```
C:\my_mongo_dir\bin>mongod --dbpath .\data\db
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the data/db directory in your main (windows) partition:

```
C:\> mkdir \data
C:\> mkdir \data\db
```

and then go to your mongo_directory/bin and run mongod.exe:

```
C:\> cd \my_mongo_dir\bin

C:\my_mongo_dir\bin> mongod
```

DON't CLOSE THIS WINDOW

Now in a different command prompt window run Mongo:

```
C:\> cd \my_mongo_dir\bin
C:\my_mongo_dir\bin> mongo
```

(REMEMBER YOU HAVE TO KEEP THAT OTHER WINDOW OPEN)

This solved the problem for me.

Comment: >> mongod --install --dbpath c:\data\db --logpath c:\data\log

 >> net start "Mongo DB"

 // note: net start may need admin permission

Answer (score 1):

Also check if you have installed the Mongo as a windows service and if its running. That's also important. There might port conflict because of that.

Answer (score 1):

create folder structure data/db in the working directory and then starting up mongodb using  "mongod --dbpath data/db" works just fine

Answer (score 1):

You should create a `startup.bat` if you're using Windows, much more convenient:

```
C:\mongodb\mongodb-win32-x86_64-eiditon\bin\mongod.exe --dbpath C:\mongodb\data
```

And just dbclick startup.bat and mongodb will run using `C:\mongodb\data` as its data folder.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create directory in C:. as C:\data\db\

Now just start mongoDB:

```
C:\Users\gi.gupta>"c:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin\mongod.exe"
2016-05-03T10:49:30.412+0530 I CONTROL  [main] Hotfix KB2731284 or later update is not installed, will zero-out data files
2016-05-03T10:49:30.414+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=7904 port=27017 dbpath=C:\data\db\ 64-bit host=GLTPM-W036
2016-05-03T10:49:30.414+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
2016-05-03T10:49:30.414+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.6
2016-05-03T10:49:30.414+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 05552b562c7a0b3143a729aaa0838e558dc49b25
2016-05-03T10:49:30.414+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1p-fips 9 Jul 2015
2016-05-03T10:49:30.414+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2016-05-03T10:49:30.414+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-05-03T10:49:30.414+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-05-03T10:49:30.414+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: 2008plus-ssl
2016-05-03T10:49:30.414+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-05-03T10:49:30.414+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-05-03T10:49:30.414+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2016-05-03T10:49:30.427+0530 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in C:\data\db\ created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to
2016-05-03T10:49:30.429+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=1G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(f
chive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2016-05-03T10:49:30.998+0530 I NETWORK  [HostnameCanonicalizationWorker] Starting hostname canonicalization worker
2016-05-03T10:49:30.998+0530 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory 'C:/data/db/diagnostic.data'
2016-05-03T10:49:31.000+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2016-05-03T10:49:40.766+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:57504 #1 (1 connection now open)
```

It will then run as service in background.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows 7/ 7+.

Here is something you can try.

> Check if the installation is proper in CONTROL PANEL of your computer.

Now goto the directory and where you've install the MongoDB. Ideally, it would be in

> C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin

Then either in the command prompt or in the IDE's terminal. Navigate to the above path ( Ideally your save file) and type

> mongod --dbpath

It should work alright!

Answer (score 0):

The very simplest approach given by mongo README help file

RUNNING

For command line options invoke:

```
$ ./mongod --help
```

To run a single server database:

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /data/db
$ ./mongod
$
$ # The mongo javascript shell connects to localhost and test database by default:
$ ./mongo
> help
```

**If you are working with windows,** go to your directory where you have mongo.exe

use the following commands, (I am sharing mine)

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin>mkdir \data

C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin>mkdir \data\db

C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin>mongod ## this will start your mongoDB server
```

Now you need to run another CMD prompt and go to the directory where you have mongo and just run it

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin>mongo ## this will start your mongoDB client
```

Hope it helped :)

**If it doesn't work, run CMD as an administrator**