# MongoDB launch issue

Tags: mongodb

New to MongoDB. Tried launching the Mongo instance as below and encountered the below issue.

Any suggestions?

```
E:\mongodb\mongodb-win32-i386-2.6.1\bin>mongo.exe
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.1
connecting to: test
2014-05-27T22:13:20.253+0530 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reas
on: errno:10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively
refused it.
2014-05-27T22:13:20.258+0530 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (
127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146
exception: connect failed
```

Comment: did you start the server (`mongod.exe`) before running `mongo.exe`?

Comment: did you create drive:\data\db  folder?

Comment: @Makoton that would be a different error. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029064/new-to-mongodb-can-not-run-command-mongo

Comment: When something actively rejects it is most likely the firewall

Comment: @Sammaye or the server is not running, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12993494/347455.